# Where do I find system.web.Http in .NET CORE 2.0 project

Tags: asp.net-core

i need use System.Web.Http in my project.
I found that  Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core package has it, but in NET core project I have error:
Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.4' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Can you help?